# Vaadin ComboBox: Select date of birth?

Tags: java, eclipse, combobox, grid, vaadin

I am trying to develop a simple web application with vaadin, in which I want my the user to enter his name, surname, mail adress and date of birth. Each works fine, except the ComboBox for the date of birth selcetion. Day and Month are allright, but to fill the box for the year, I used the following code:

```
`for (int i = 1900; i < 2016; i++)
    {
        year.addItem(i);
    }`
```

(the ComboBox is called 'year'). The result I get is a list from 1.900 to 1.908. What is wrong with my code? Need help soon.

Thx, simon1440

Comment: According to your comment, the only answer is correct. Mark it as answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think converting int to String should help:

```
for (int i = 1900; i < 2016; i++)
    {
        year.addItem(String.valueOf(i));
    }
```

[Here](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.vaadin.ui.ComboBox) you can see more examples with combobox. Your case is similar to example#2.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem of how the numbers are presented. Now I have the problem, that I cannot scroll down until the last element of the ComboBox, but only until 1908. Then I have to hit the down arrow in the ComboBox. What can I do in order to be able to completely scroll down until the last element?

Comment: If you do not changing i (except i++), so maybe year combobox has a size, that is filled by 1900-1908 only. Try to debug or add system.out.println before  year.addItem(String.valueOf(i)); to see how many times for runs.

Comment: Ok, I understood your problem 
Maybe this will help you https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/142751/5035034. You need to increase your page size.

Comment: You could also try to use a NativeSelect instead of a ComboBox.